# Update my database from Select result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
mysql> SELECT Ext, Pass, Name, Context FROM temp_Users WHERE temp_Users.Pass NOT IN (SELECT Pass FROM Users);
+------+-------+---------+------------+
| Ext  | Pass  | Name    | Context    |
+------+-------+---------+------------+
| 6003 | Hello | WebPone | DLPN_Admin |
+------+-------+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> UPDATE Users
    -> SET (Pass, Name, Context) = (SELECT  Pass, Name, Context FROM temp_Users WHERE temp_Users.Pass NOT IN (SELECT Pass FROM Users))
    -> WHERE Users.Ext = temp.Ext;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Pass, Name, Context) = (SELECT  Pass, Name, Context FROM temp_Users WHERE temp_' at line 2
```

I want to update my database from Select result and i am getting this error. Please tell me how i can resolve it ?

Comment: Not to be rude, but your attempt wasn't even close.  It looks like you wrote what you wished the syntax would be, [instead of checking what the actual syntax is](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)...

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson: In all fairness, there are some DBMSes that support a syntax much like the OP's. If (s)he Googled for "SQL" update statements rather than "MySQL" update statements, (s)he might well have ended up with something like that. (Not everyone knows how different the different SQL dialects can be.)

Comment: @ruakh  Interesting, I stand corrected.  Just for my curiosity, do you know which SQL dialect(s) allows that?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson: Oracle does. (I originally wrote "DBMSes", plural, because I had thought PostgreSQL did as well, but now I see that although PostgreSQL supports `SET (a, b, c) = (d, e, f)`, it doesn't let you replace the `(d, e, f)` part with a *single* subquery that returns *multiple* fields. I guess the reason for the difference is that whereas MySQL and PostgreSQL each offer "join"-like `UPDATE` syntaxes, Oracle does not, so it makes up for that by offering a syntax for setting multiple fields to a multiple-field subquery.)

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson
Please take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003011/oracle-10g-pl-sql-select-results-as-update-column-values

Comment: @ruakh: Have you checked my above link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support the `SET ( multiple_fields ) = ( subquery_that_returns_multiple_fields )` syntax for `UPDATE` statements. Instead, you have to use a "multiple-table" update (a join). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html.

Your query has some other problems as well, so I'm not clear on *exactly* what you want . . . but I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE users
  JOIN temp_users
    ON temp_users.ext = users.ext
   SET users.pass = temp_users.pass,
       users.name = temp_users.name,
       users.context = temp_users.context
 WHERE temp_users.pass NOT IN
        -- extra subquery to bypass MySQL limitation:
        ( SELECT pass
            FROM ( SELECT pass
                     FROM users
                 ) t
        )
;
```

Comment: +1 @ruakh, You were right on both counts... you have to have the prefix on the left side, otherwise it complains that it is ambiguous, and you have to add the extra subquery for the `IN`.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Users u
JOIN temp_Users tu ON tu.Ext = u.Ext
SET 
    Pass = tu.Pass,
    Name = tu.Name,
    Context = tu.Context
WHERE tu.Pass NOT IN (
    SELECT Pass
    FROM Users
)
```

Comment: Sir, If I am not only keeping i on Password changes, I need to keep i also on Name and Context, then what should i do ?

Comment: Are you sure that you can just write e.g. `Pass = tu.Pass` rather than `u.Pass = tu.Pass`? That seems odd to me. And are you sure you can have `NOT IN (SELECT Pass FROM Users)` at the top level when `Users` is one of the tables being updated? The documentation states that "Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery."

Comment: @ruakh Good questions, I'll double check.  I know that in SQL Server, it will actually throw an error if you try to prefix the left side of the assignment in an update, but not sure about MySql.  I'll also double-check the validity of the `IN`.